# opencv - cmake error : No such file or directory on Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I have been trying to install opencv from source rather than pip since I could not read a VideoCapture successfully.

Installing **opencv-3.2.0** on **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**. Followed the details mentioned [here](https://github.com/kratzert/Ubuntu_from_scratch/blob/master/Ubuntu_16_04LTS.md#installing-opencv3).

I get the following errors in ".../opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log":

```
.../opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory


.../opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
```

**libv4l-dev** is already the newest version (1.10.0-1)

I've also run the following command at **/usr/include/linux**:

```
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```

The CMake output is:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2017-08-09T05:39:43Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.5.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 atk-1.0 cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pango-1.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 fontconfig freetype gthread-2.0 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutil-ffmpeg swscale-ffmpeg dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp IlmImf
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab python2 python3
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java viz
--
--   GUI:
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.30)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    YES/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
--
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /root/twix/tensorflow/opencv-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
--
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /root/twix/tensorflow/opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
--
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
--
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
--
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
--
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /root/twix/tensorflow/opencv-3.2.0/build
--
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: does the `cmake` command or the `make` command generate your mentioned errors? also, did you verify that the file `/usr/include/linux/videodev.h` (after creating the symlink) exists?

Comment: @BNT this was the `cmake` command. Yes, I can see that `/usr/include/linux/videodev.h` has been created.

Comment: Everyone is replying about the `linux/videodev.h` but why noone is take about the `sys/videoio.h`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This seems really silly in retrospect but the cmake command has a path option for `-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules`. This path was incorrect on my system. I changed it to the correct path and it worked. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: that means you are following step that I mention in my answer

Answer (score 4):

For your problem, you have to run following command

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

for install OpenCV on Ubuntu, I always following some step that always works.

I install OpenCV with opencv_contrib ( some extra module for OpenCV)

Open terminal and run following command

To install opencv dependency

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev

sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
```

To install opencv

1. cd /opt/
2. sudo git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
3. sudo git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
4. cd opencv
5. sudo mkdir release
6. cd release
7. sudo cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib/modules -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  /opt/opencv/
8. sudo make
9. sudo make install
10. pkg-config --modversion opencv   # check version installed

If you don't want to install opencv_contrib you can skip 3rd step and change  7 step to

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D 
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D /opt/opencv/
```

Comment: I already have all these dependencies installed. Please check the link I shared. it's pretty much the same thing you mentioned. This doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Twix install opencv with openc_contrib and i also update 7 th step command please check

Comment: Yes, I'm installing with openc_contrib. The only difference between what you said and what [this](https://github.com/kratzert/Ubuntu_from_scratch/blob/master/Ubuntu_16_04LTS.md#installing-opencv3) says is that use have the INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES set to ON. Tried that. Didnt work.

Comment: @Twix As a workaround, "-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF" works for me and  check your gcc --version && g++ --version if >= 4.9. if not , you must update or reinstall them.

Comment: The `-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF` doesn't work. I tried that the first time around. g++ version is 5.4

Comment: @Twxx then check link where same issue is closed that  help  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6262

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in Twix's answer. You should modify path according to your directory structure for following commands

```
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules \
```

And also for one more command(see below) if you are using

```
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
```

It works for me too!